# how can I get text from nested div?

Tags: jquery

I have situation like this:

```
<div id="test" class="word">
    Ele
    <div id="inner-dropzone" class="dropzone">
       ph
    </div>
    ant
</div>
```

And I would like to get whole text from div#test (Elephant).
I tried `$('#test').text()` but i got only 'ant'.

Have you any idea?
Regards

Comment: @Satpal: that will even give html win it.

Comment: @Satpal that'll also include the `<div>` code. `.text()` seems like the right thing, i don't know why it's not working.

Comment: When I run `$('#test').text()` I get `Ele
    phant `. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/7vY42/

Comment: Seems to work for me... http://jsfiddle.net/EsH75/1/

Comment: I am getting `Elephant` with using `.text()` as expected. Check console in http://jsfiddle.net/rP9Xf/

Comment: If it is always going to be a single word and you want to remove the spaces, use `$('#test').text().replace(/\s/gm,"")`

Comment: thanks you guys, i have stupid bug in my code ;/. Thanks again ;)